# Caret position getting to 0

Tags: javascript

I have contenteditable div and simple syntax highlights from js. Yes, js have some problems after it finds word like let, and const to highlight and converting to `<span class="dataType">const</span>` my caret location getting to 0; I tried everything and gave up, now I'm on StackOverflow and asking this question.

here's me code:

```
const editor = document.getElementById("editor");
let previousText = "";

editor.addEventListener("input", function () {
  const currentText = editor.textContent;

  if (currentText.length < previousText.length) {
    previousText = currentText;
    return;
  }

  const addedText = currentText.substring(previousText.length);
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const startOffset = selection.anchorOffset;

  const keywords = [
    "function",
    "var",
    "let",
    "const",
    "if",
    "else",
    "for",
    "while",
    "return",
  ];
  const keywordPattern = new RegExp(`\\b(${keywords.join("|")})\\b`, "g");

  if (keywordPattern.test(addedText)) {
    const highlightedText = addedText.replace(
      keywordPattern,
      '<span class="keyword">$&</span>'
    );
    const newText =
      currentText.substring(0, startOffset) +
      highlightedText +
      currentText.substring(startOffset + addedText.length);
    editor.innerHTML = newText;
    const newOffset = startOffset + highlightedText.length;
    selection.setPosition(editor.firstChild, newOffset);
  } else {
    const fullText = currentText;
    const highlightedText = fullText.replace(
      keywordPattern,
      '<span class="keyword">$&</span>'
    );
    editor.innerHTML = highlightedText;
    const newOffset = startOffset;
    selection.setPosition(editor.firstChild, newOffset);
  }

  previousText = currentText;
});

editor.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const br = document.createElement("br");
    range.insertNode(br);
    range.setStartAfter(br);
    range.setEndAfter(br);
    range.collapse(false);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
});
```

I also tried to check the current position save it and after applying syntax lighting use it to correct the caret location but, I got an error that the location of that `contenteditable` div never exists there then I tried to search on StackOverflow but nothing useful to my project.

And also error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Selection.setPosition: The offset is out of range.
```

Additional info:
Using the latest Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I've played with your challenge, and you can see result below in code snipped.

I removed the listener for `keydown` for `Enter` and instead of this I use css rules `white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;`, and my example work not fine, some times when you type `'` or `"` it jumping forward. Maybe it will be helpfull for you and you will find some ways for make it perfect.

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("editor");

const keywords = [
  "function",
  "var",
  "let",
  "const",
  "if",
  "else",
  "for",
  "while",
  "return",
];

function wrapKeywords() {
  const contentDiv = document.getElementById("editor");
  const text = contentDiv.innerText;
  const selection = window.getSelection();

  const startOffset = selection.focusOffset;
  const endOffset = text.length;

  const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${keywords.join('|')})\\b`, 'g');

  const newText = text.replace(regex, '<span class="keyword">$&</span>');

  contentDiv.innerHTML = newText;

  moveCursorToEnd();
}

function moveCursorToEnd() {
  const editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  const range = document.createRange();
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(editor, editor.childNodes.length);
  range.collapse(true);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}

editor.addEventListener("input", wrapKeywords);
```

```css
#editor {
  min-height: 120px;
  min-width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.keyword {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: The highlights look good, but when I try to go next line by clicking enter it makes a large whitespace. If I try to remove those new lines, that is not possible.